# Blank object in Eloquent belongsTo()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to display which one attribute (`code`) of Item. ServiceItem has Item as a foreign key. But I can't get the Item at all.

This one gives a blank object in blade template:

```
@foreach ($service->serviceItems as $serviceItem )
    {{ json_encode($serviceItem->item()) }}
@endforeach
```

[image]

Here's my model declaration:

```
//ServiceItem model
class ServiceItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $fillable = ['service_id', 'item_id', 'values'];

    public function service()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class, 'foreign_key');
    }

    // this doesn't work
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'foreign_key');
    }
}

// Service model
class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $fillable = ['user_id', 'site_id', 'title', 'status', 'remarks', 'report', 'date'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }

    public function site()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Site');
    }

    public function serviceItems() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ServiceItem');
    }

}
```

This is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $services = Service::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('services.index', compact('services'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Please help me to display the `code` attribute in Item from Service!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you would be using the dynamic property, `$serviceItem->item`, not the method to access the relationship; the method would return a relationship builder object not a result ... but the dynamic property could return `null` since Belongs To could return a model or `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you read the Laravel doc of model relationship definition. They referenced to put foreign key as the second parameter, not the `foreign_key` as word but your actual foreign key that reference the parent table. you have to change the model code.

```
class ServiceItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $fillable = ['service_id', 'item_id', 'values'];

    public function service()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class, 'service_id');
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'item_id');
    }
}
```

and then `$serviceItem->item` should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, it works! So the second param of belongsTo() have to be the column name of the table, correct?

Comment: ya, that's correct.